# Codeigniter load->view safe to change headers AFTER loading view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is the following code safe to do in this context? (Modifying headers after output). I did a quick look at the `function view` and it appears to do output buffering so I think I am ok, I just want to confirm that I can modify headers in this context. I didn't get any PHP Notices, but I just want to confirm this is ok.

```
class theController extends CI_Controller
{
    function example()
    {
        $this->load->view("sales/receipt",$data);       
        //Not really what I am doing, but just as an example
       header_remove ('Set-Cookie'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to change headers after you output something, it will have no effect.

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

So, it is safe, but it is also useless!

If you want to delete cookies when a page is loaded, you should do it right before the output.

Comment: I think codeigniter output buffers. The headers I am sending are actually taking effect. I am just wondering if anyone has internal knowledge